# Mysterious lifetime issue while implementing trait for dyn object

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

Consider the following toy example:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

pub trait SimpleOrder {
    fn key(&self) -> u32;
}

impl PartialOrd for dyn SimpleOrder {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for dyn SimpleOrder {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> Ordering {
        self.key().cmp(&other.key())
    }
}

impl PartialEq for dyn SimpleOrder {
    fn eq(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> bool {
        self.key() == other.key()
    }
}

impl Eq for SimpleOrder {}
```

This doesn't compile. It claims there is a lifetime issue in the implementation for `partial_cmp`:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:9:23
  |
9 |         Some(self.cmp(other))
  |                       ^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method body at 8:5...
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 | /     fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> Option<Ordering> {
9 | |         Some(self.cmp(other))
10| |     }
  | |_____^
note: ...so that the declared lifetime parameter bounds are satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:23
  |
9 |         Some(self.cmp(other))
  |                       ^^^^^
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected std::cmp::Eq
             found std::cmp::Eq
```

I really don't understand this error. In particular *"expected `std::cmp::Eq` found `std::cmp::Eq`"* is puzzling.

If I inline the call manually it compiles fine:

```
fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> Option<Ordering> {
    Some(self.key().cmp(&other.key()))
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This **is** mysterious!

Comment: Since we are talking about traits... `'static` is probably missing somewhere?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Why is a static lifetime required for the argument of `partial_cmp` but not for `cmp`?

Comment: @PeterHall: I have no idea, but I think that this may be the clue behind the "expected std::cmp::Eq found std::cmp::Eq", one has a `'static` lifetime that is not shown, while the other doesn't. I am certainly looking forward to the answer of this question :D

Comment: `fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &(dyn SimpleOrder + 'static)) -> Option<Ordering>` works ;)

Comment: A much simpler reproduction of the issue: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9651de4c79c6f68b0d155f4e72dfa97

Comment: Using `Self` instead of `dyn SimpleOrder` also works. I suspect this has something to do with lifetime elision.

Comment: @trentcl: Probably. I guess `Self` is deduced to be `dyn SimpleOrder + 'static`, and `dyn SimpleOrder`, as an argument, is treated as "potentially something else entirely".

Comment: Yes, `fn f(&self, o: &dyn Trt)` is equal to `fn<'a> f(&self, o: &'a (dyn Trt + 'a)`. But @PeterHall note that your reproduction actually produces a different (albeit similar) issue. The issue in orlp's code is triggered by rust typechecking against the signature of `cmp` of the `Ord` trait instead of the actual implementation. Otherwise his code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Chronial I think it's the same. What I narrowed in on was the fact that one method calls another. The issue doesn't occur when they don't call each other.

Comment: @PeterHall if you copy the `cmp` implementation into the `SimpleOrder` trait, rename it to `mycmp` and then call that in `partial_cmp`, the code will compile.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Trait object types have an associated lifetime bound, but it can be omitted. A full trait object type is written `dyn Trait + 'a` (when behind a reference, parentheses must be added around it: `&(dyn Trait + 'a)`).

The tricky part is that when a lifetime bound is omitted, [the rules are a bit complicated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes).

First, we have:

```
impl PartialOrd for dyn SimpleOrder {
```

Here, the compiler infers `+ 'static`. Lifetime parameters are never introduced on `impl` blocks (as of Rust 1.32.0).

Next, we have:

```
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &dyn SimpleOrder) -> Option<Ordering> {
```

The type of `other` is inferred to be `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)`, where `'b` is an implicit lifetime parameter introduced on `partial_cmp`.

```
    fn partial_cmp<'a, 'b>(&'a self, other: &'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)) -> Option<Ordering> {
```

So now we have that `self` has type `&'a (dyn SimpleOrder + 'static)` while `other` has type `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)`. What's the problem?

Indeed, `cmp` doesn't give any error, because its implementation doesn't require that the lifetime of the two trait objects be equal. Why does `partial_cmp` care, though?

Because `partial_cmp` is calling `Ord::cmp`. When type checking a call to a trait method, the compiler checks against the signature from the trait. Let's review that signature:

```
pub trait Ord: Eq + PartialOrd<Self> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering;
```

The trait requires that `other` be of type `Self`. That means that when `partial_cmp` calls `cmp`, it tries to pass a `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)` to a parameter that expects a `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'static)`, because `Self` is `dyn SimpleOrder + 'static`. This conversion is not valid (`'b` cannot be converted to `'static`), so the compiler gives an error.

So then, why is it valid to set the type of `other` to `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)` when implementing `Ord`? Because `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'b)` is a [supertype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) of `&'b (dyn SimpleOrder + 'static)`, and Rust lets you replace a parameter type with one of its supertypes when implementing a trait method (it makes the method strictly more general, even though it's apparently not used much in type checking).

---

In order to make your implementation as generic as possible, you should introduce a lifetime parameter on the `impl`s:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

pub trait SimpleOrder {
    fn key(&self) -> u32;
}

impl<'a> PartialOrd for dyn SimpleOrder + 'a {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<'a> Ord for dyn SimpleOrder + 'a {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.key().cmp(&other.key())
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for dyn SimpleOrder + 'a {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key() == other.key()
    }
}

impl<'a> Eq for dyn SimpleOrder + 'a {}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I do believe that the error message generated by Rust should be improved though - that this is the issue isn't *at all* clear from the error message.

Comment: "So now we have that self has type &(dyn SimpleOrder + 'a) while other has type &(dyn SimpleOrder + 'static)." – this should be the other way round, right?

Comment: @Chronial oops, fixed.

Comment: The thing that is surprising to me here is that calling `SimpleOrder::cmp(self, other)` does not check against the signature of `SimpleOrder::cmp` (which would succeed), but against the signature of `Ord::cmp` (which fails).

Comment: @Chronial: I think this would warrant its own (separate) question; notably, I guess it would be possible to trigger the behavior without `dyn Trait`, just exploiting sub-typing with regular types containing references.

Comment: What surprises *me* is that this doesn't match the behavior of `Box<dyn SimpleOrder>` (it's not treated as a free parameter, but always as `'static`). There must be something special about references. Did you refer to any particular documentation to write this answer? I can't find anything that explicitly describes how lifetime parameters on trait objects are inferred.

Comment: @trentcl No, I just experimented in the playground. I noticed in particular that introducing the explicit lifetime in `partial_cmp`'s signature (as written in my answer) didn't change the compiler's behavior, so I assumed both forms were equivalent.

Comment: @trentcl I remember reading somewhere that `&'a T` is equal to `&'a (T + 'a)`. That does also fit the behavior of `Box` (non-references are `'static`). Ah, found the reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes

Comment: @Chronial Thanks for the reference! I've incorporated it into my answer and edited it accordingly.