# Why implementation of iterator is not generic enough in async context?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

[Cross posting on github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71671)

Given the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bece604aa99c31dc710f5f3129296f1f) snippet:

```rust
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

async fn from_bar(bar: &[Vec<&u8>]) {
    let x = bar.iter().flat_map(|i| i.iter().map(|_| async { 42 }));
    let foo: Vec<_> = stream::iter(x).collect().await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for bar in vec![] {
        tokio::spawn(async {
            from_bar(bar).await;
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         tokio::spawn(async {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected type `std::ops::FnOnce<(&&u8,)>`
              found type `std::ops::FnOnce<(&&u8,)>`

error: implementation of `std::iter::Iterator` is not general enough
    --> src/main.rs:11:9
     |
11   |           tokio::spawn(async {
     |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `std::iter::Iterator` is not general enough
     |
     = note: `std::iter::Iterator` would have to be implemented for the type `std::slice::Iter<'0, &u8>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
     = note: ...but `std::iter::Iterator` is actually implemented for the type `std::slice::Iter<'1, &u8>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I was expecting no error because the lifetimes seem to be correct to me. Note that removing `main()` or removing the code inside `from_bar()` *both* eliminate the errors. Not only that, the error messages are also very strange. They may be related to [a regression in the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341465/rust-expected-type-error-prints-mismatched-types-that-are-exactly-the-same/54344401#54344401), though more than that they seem to be in the wrong place ([maybe related](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54326)).

Version `rustc 1.43.0 (4fb7144ed 2020-04-20)`:

```
[dependencies]
futures = '0.3.1'

[dependencies.tokio]
version = '0.2'
features = ['full']
```

Answer (score -1):

Slightly simpler reproduction:

```
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

async fn from_bar(bar: &[Vec<&u8>]) {
    let x = bar.iter().flat_map(|i| i.iter().map(|_| async { 42 }));
    let foo: Vec<_> = stream::iter(x).collect().await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        from_bar(&vec![]).await;
    });
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=384cb8752c9ab746b936e22a391a6ad5).

This example makes what's wrong clearer: the reference that you pass to `from_bar` only lives until the end of `main` (or possibly even the current loop iteration in your example), but `spawn` needs it to live longer than that since the spawned task may run longer.

What I don't understand is how this translates into the error message we get…

Comment: This doesn't preserve the semantics of what OP was doing; he seems to want to apply `from_bar` iteratively to every element of a `Vec`.

Edit: This is a case of an unhelpful error message, and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64650) out about it. Please see my answer specifying this below.

Comment: @HariAmoor the question wasn't "How to make this work", but "Why is this an error". My answer reproduces the same error and explains why it there is an error.

Comment: no the vector is consume, the object is moved in the async block. The code compile fine with imperative style so it's not a lifetime problem. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=329421030c183f9db057e0f640a17a0c

Comment: The async block is only evaluated inside the `spawn`, since `async` blocks are lazy. Therefore Jmb is right - this wouldn't make sense anyway. I think the modified example might work because it infers from the requirements that the arguments passed to `from_bar` must be static (&'static [Vec<&'static u8>])`. And that `vec![]` generates an empty vector of static references which also satisfies that criteria.